# I can not find the reason “ERROR: Cannot read property ‘toString’ of undefined”

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, repository

this is my first question on the stack, so I don't know if I am describing it well.
I have a problem because after putting the data into the input (form) with the parameter "edit" selected
, it does not indicate the selected record.
Currently, I still get the error "Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" ", please advise me

controlers:

```
exports.editWynajmyList = (req, res, next) => {
    const wynId = req.params.wynId;
    WynajmyRepository.getWynajmyById(wynId)
    .then(wyn => {
    res.render('pages/wynajmy-form', {
        wyn: wyn,
        formMode: 'edit',
        pageTitle: 'Edycja wynajmy',
        btnLabel: 'Edytuj wynajm',
        formAction: '/wynajmy/edit',
        navLocation: 'wyn'});
    });
}
```

Repository:

```
exports.getWynajmyById = (wynId) => {
    const query = `SELECT w._id as w_id, w.data_rozp, w.data_zak, w.ubezp, a._id as a_id, a.vin, a.marka, a.model, a.rocznik, a.model_silnika, a.wyposazenie, k.imie, k.nazwisko 
    FROM Wynajmy w
    left join Klienci k on w.kli_id = k._id
    left join Auta a on w.aut_id=a._id
    where w._id=?`
    return db.promise().query(query, [wynId])
        .then((results, fields) => {
            const row = results[0][0];
            if(!row){
                return{};
            }
        const wynajmy = {
            _id: wynId,
            data_rozp: row.data_rozp,
            data_zak: row.data_zak,
            ubezp: row.ubezp,
            auto: {
                _id: row.aut_id,
                vin: row.vin,
                marka: row.marka,
                model: row.model,
                rocznik: row.rocznik,
                model_silnika: row.model_silnika,
                wyposazenie: row.wyposazenie
            },
            klient: {
                _id: row.kli_id,
                imie: row.imie,
                nazwisko: row.nazwisko,
                pesel: row.pesel
            }
        };
        console.log(wynajmy);
        return wynajmy;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        });
};
```

.ejs

```
<label for="vin">VIN pojazdu:<sup>*</sup></label>
            <select id="vin" name="aut_id" required <%=(formMode=='showDetails' ) ? 'disabled' : '' %> >
                <option value="" selected>--- Wybierz auto ---</option>
                <% for (let i=0; i<allAuts.length; i++) { let aut=allAuts[i]; %>
                    <option value="<%= aut._id %>" label="<%= aut.vin %>" <%=(wyn._id && aut._id.toString() == wyn.auto._id.toString() ) ? 'selected' : '' %>></option>
                    <% } %>
                </select>
                <span id="errorVIN" class="errors-text"></span>
```

Comment: Your error message means that one of your aut objects or autos doesn't have an _id.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Cannot read property toString of undefined" means that you are calling `toString()` on something that doesn't exist (is undefined). In your code I can see that you called `toString()` on 'aut._id' while I think the property you mean is auto._id.

```js
<%=(wyn._id && auto._id.toString() == wyn.auto._id.toString() ) ?  // auto instead of aut
```